Can any point process be thinned into a homogenous Poisson point process?
Let $X$ be a stationary and isotropic point process. Under what sufficient conditions can $X$ be thinned into an (approximation of an) homogenous Poisson point process $Y$ of positive intensity?
What I have tried
This question is a re-post of a question I asked in Cross Validated which received attention but no answers.  I also posed a variant which assumed that $X$ is the thinning of a homogenous Poisson point process $\Phi$.
Possibly unlike Møller & Schoenberg (2010) and Schoenberg (2009), I am not concerned with a practical procedure for obtaining $Y$ from $X$, only in establishing that $X$ exists. Nor am I necessarily limited to $p$-thinning (independent or otherwise): I noted that (independent?) $p$-thinning of a mixed binomial process will yield another mixed binomial process and the relationship between Cox processes and the existence of $p$-inverses. My conclusion is a more sophisticated thinning procedure may be needed.
I reviewed literature relating to residual analysis of spatial point processes (stemming from Baddeley et al, 2005). This literature takes the position of a Poisson point process being the residual "error" (my interpretation) in fitting a model to a data set. Thus in my reading, Møller & Schoenberg (2010) assume that $X$ is the superposition of a homogenous Poisson point process and another process.
A tangible example I work with - see also Edit 1 below: Let $X$ be a Matérn hard core point process. Can $X$ be further thinned into a homogenous Poisson point process? Note that $X$ is itself thinned from a homogenous Poisson point process $\Phi$, by dependent thinning. My intuition (hope?) was that the hard core "anti-bunching" in $X$ could be removed by further thinning.
The nearest I have gotten is: Goldman (1967) has a limit theorem and sufficient conditions for $p$-thinning a stationary point process into a mixed Poisson process. So can any mixed Poisson process (or close approximation) be thinned into a homogenous Poisson process of intensity $\lambda > 0$?
Otherwise: If $\Phi$ has intensity $\kappa$ and $\Phi_p$ is an independent $p$-thinning of $\Phi$ then $\Phi_p$ is a homogenous Poisson point process of intensity $p\kappa$. Thus I played with assuming that $X$ is a thinning of $\Phi$.
Edit 1: As noted by @JamesMartin: Let $X$ be a Matérn hard core point process with inhibition distance $r$. Then $X$ can never be thinned into a homogenous Poisson point process because such a process has positive probability of points being within distance $r$ of each other. Can an approximation be reached? Perhaps by thinning and rescaling, in which the intensity is held constant?
References
Møller, J., & Schoenberg, F. P. (2010). Thinning Spatial Point Processes into Poisson Processes. Advances in Applied Probability, 42(2), 347–358.
Goldman, Jay R. (1967, June). Stochastic Point Processes: Limit Theorems. Ann. Math. Statist. 38(3), 771-779.
Baddeley, A., Turner R., Møller,  J., & Hazelton, M. Residual analysis for spatial point processes (with discussion). Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology), 67: 617-666.
Schoenberg, F. P. (2009). On thinning a spatial point process into a Poisson process using the Papangelou intensity.

Maybe I misunderstand, but it looks like a "Mátern hard-core point process" has probability zero to have two points within distance $r$ of each other. This property is preserved under any thinning procedure. But a homogeneous Poisson process has positive probability to have two points within distance $r$ of each other. So no thinning of a Mátern hard-core point process can be a homogeneous Poisson process.

@JamesMartin Yes, that's a very good point, and possibly a fatal one. The tickle in my brain is as follows: Let $X$ be (the realisation of) a Mátern hard-core point process. Perhaps if $Y$ is a very "aggressive" thinning of $X$ then it will be a good approximation to a homogenous Poisson process, becoming perfect in the limit? So yes, there are no points within distance $r$, but on the big scale the $r$ looks like it is tending to zero?

I agree, it sounds like that sort of scheme should work!
